# Creating tool to add blog tags: when the post is submitted the dynamically added tags are ignored

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

I'm trying to create a simple tool to ease the addition of tags in blog posts (not sure if I can mention the website, therefore i won't do it now).
I've inspected the code and I've noticed that when a tag is added, a new span is created between the `divs` `post-form--tag-editor` and `tag-input-wrapper`

```
<div class="post-form--tag-editor" data-subview="tagEditor">
-> TAG CODE here !! <span class=""> ::before This is a tag </span> <- TAG CODE here!!!
<span class=""> ::before This is another tag </span>
<div class="tag-input-wrapper" data-js-taginputfieldwrapper="">
<div data-name="tagInput" data-subview="tagInputField">
<div data-js="editor-wrapper" class="editor-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
```

Right now, my tool is injecting the necessary HTML to create dynamic spans and add new tags. I can see my "injected" tags in the webpage but when I submit the post the "injected" tags do not appear in the live post.

Since I'm able to see the "injected tags" shouldn't I be able to see them too when my post is submitted and live ? Am I using the wrong approach  to achieve what I want?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: showing us related css would probably be helpful

Comment: css ? Why ? I mean, if the class of my "injected" spans is the same as the tags I insert manually I think the properties are the same for both.

Comment: Was thinking maybe there was something in the class description in css that is causing the hiccup. not likely but always something to check .

Comment: Can you please be more precise so i can more or less know what I'm looking for.